# Pushing to array removes old data (React Native)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to push text input into an array. When I modify the input text and push it, the array is wiped before the push (not showing my previous pushes in the console.log). What am I missing?

```js
const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Text');

let chatHistory = [];

function logHistory(text) {
  chatHistory.push(text);
  console.log(chatHistory);
}

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
      <Button title={'Ask the computer...'} onPress={() => logHistory(text)} />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: The only time you should use variables directly within a react class is if you are going to mutate said variables *before* rendering. If you declare a variable before rendering and then mutate it after rendering, then you should use state instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I supposed that because you change state, it rerender this component and redeclare chatHistory as empty array.
use `useState` for chatHistory instead.

And instead of Array.push i recommend to use `chatHistory = [...chatHistory, text]`,in useState case `setChatHistory([...chatHistory,text])`;

Answer (score 2):

If you want the changes in `chatHistory` to be reflected on your component you need to use a state and not just a plain variable. Such variables do not survive through re-renders and anything you store in regular variables will be lost. Try out after making these changes

```js
const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = React.useState([]);

function logHistory(text) {
  setChatHistory((history) => [...history, text]);
}
```

Also the `console.log` statement might  not give you the result you are expecting. You might also want to display the chat history somewhere maybe in a flat list.